# Where do i start when trying to get webservice API's integrated?

Tags: 7, services

I am building a travel website for a client, and we need search form tied to different API's and in some cases combined API's returning results.

I am a seasoned PHP developer, but fairly new to Drupal.

Where should I start? what modules should i be looking at?

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very active group of developers working with the [Services module](http://drupal.org/project/services). I am sure that another seasoned PHP developer would be welcomed by them.

Comment: That is a good start!  Sorry.. should have done some more searching before asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use external web services and not create WebAPIs of your own, check out:
http://drupal.org/node/1070066.

In that Drupal.org docs page, I overview two methods for someone to communicate with a Services.module created WebAPI. If your situation is communicating with 3rd party web services, you need to do something similar. Logic like the section labled "Using the Drupal API to communicate with a RESTful API" is what you'll need.

Comment: This is awesome, and exactly what i needed. Thanks d00d!